# how to get distinct elements from xml in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am generating PDF using XSLT 1.0. The data or XML which I am passing to XSLT file as:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <unit>Horizontal></unit>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <unit>Vertical</unit>
        <name>Justin</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <unit>Horizontal></unit>
        <name>Peter</name>
        <age>36</age>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

Expected output:

1. Horizontal
   . John
   . Peter
2. Vertical
   . Justin

How can I achieve this in XSLT template code? In other words, how to display distinct unit with related employees?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please try to write some code before asking. Visit this website to learn more: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Agree with @SteveFest, but we can put you on the right way. First try to get disctinct values of unit using `distinct-values(` function into a variable. Second, do a foreach on this with a condition on unit value, including another foreach to list the names.
Try this and go back if you encounter troubles

Comment: If you are indeed only using XLST 1.0, then you need to read up on Muenchian Grouping at http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html.

Comment: @PalamCoder It is expected that for some asking guys with your case Muenchian grouping can be not easy to perform, so see answer below. Please add next time your XSL you have tried to do - in that case you will avoid Down Votes from viewer guys next time.

Answer (score 1):

For the most cases similar to yours, main point is clarify by what value you will group. In your case you are grouping by non-duplicates `unit` and taking `name` values. So I suggest to create separate template (e.g. `name-group`) with structure where it will be passed parameter by which you are grouping (e.g. `param.unit`) then simply call template in loop of `employee` with duplicates preventing, as in XSL below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template name="name-group">
    <xsl:param name="param.unit"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($param.unit, '>')">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '. ', translate($param.unit, '>', ''), '&#xA;')"/>            
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '. ', $param.unit, '&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>    
    <xsl:for-each select="/employees/employee[unit = $param.unit]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('   . ', name, '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//employee">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding::employee[unit/text() = current()/unit/text()])">
            <xsl:call-template name="name-group">
                <xsl:with-param name="param.unit" select="unit"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result will be as expected:

```
1. Horizontal
   . John
   . Peter
2. Vertical
   . Justin
```

***Note!*** In next questions please put your XSL (to show everyone what you have tried) to avoid "Down Votes". Hope it will help in your case.